# Windows Server R2 2008 domain join - logon failure: unknown username or bad password

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I have this problem where I try to make a winodws machine authenticate against a ubuntu samba PDC, but i keep getting the error

```
logon failure: unknown user name or bas password
```

here is my NetSetup.log file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfr1a9gp8ye06pw/NetSetup.LOG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Probably its **time variance** (I think more than 5 minutes) between the Windows machine and samba PDC.

Either manually adjust the time on windows to match the samba PDC or install a Network Time Protocol(NTP) server  to take care of time management for your network resources.